# Processing really huge dataset using python

Tags: python, pandas

**This is a use case which I am trying to solve**

**1**. I query data from one Elastic Search DB and prepare a CSV which may have close to 50 Million rows and 15 fields.

**2.** There is a field which is an ID kind of data. I need to extract the distinct IDs from the above data set, query each one of it in an RDBMS, get the value and merge it in the above set.

**3.** Now, on this record set, I need to calculate certain parameters.

**4.** Currently I do this with Python Pandas. The issue what I am seeing is that it is taking quite a lot of time and it eats up lot of memory as well.

Could someone suggest a solution to do it faster and more efficient way ?

Comment: You can use dask instead, check it here http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html

Comment: yeah I was thinking you're real only solution is to break up the data into smaller "chunks".  Pandas read_sql has a chunksize parameter to help with this, and it seems the suggestion above is a pre-packaged solution.

Comment: Thanks Jeffery. Will check this.